# Data does not display

Tags: oracle, asp-classic

I've got minor trouble.  My data does not display.

My web page script is as follows:

```
sqlWFlexi = "Select StaffDepart,StaffName From Employee Where StaffNo = '"&myStaffNo &"'"

set rsWFlexi = ConnISAS.execute(sqlWFlexi)
if not rsWFlexi.eof then
    myWFlexi = rsWFlexi("StaffName")
end if                      
sql="Select StaffDepart, StaffName from Employee where StaffNo  = '" & myWFlexi & "'"

set rs1 = ConnISAS.execute(sql) 
if not rs1.eof then
    myDept = rs1("StaffDepart")
    myNameStaff= rs1("StaffName")

    if rs1("WFlexi") = "-" then 
        myFlexi = "0"
    else
        myFlexi = "1"
    end if
end if
```

This is supposed to display StaffName and StaffDepart.  Can you tell me what exactly is missing in my script?

Comment: You don't have any `Response.Write` there to display.... And both your sql statements look the same. What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two sql statement, if
`myWFlexi = rsWFlexi("StaffName")`get value from

`sqlWFlexi = "Select StaffDepart,StaffName From Employee Where StaffNo = '"&myStaffNo &"'"`
let just say John Smith

and second statement `sql="Select StaffDepart, StaffName from Employee where StaffNo  = '" & myWFlexi & "'"` get value from
`myWFlexi = rsWFlexi("StaffName")` that mean you want get the data StaffName and StaffDepart from employee based on the value `myWFlexi`.
The way you declare it is not right way ,that why it do not display data even you already declare `response.write`

Answer (score 0):

You have not selected WFlexi in the second sql statement. 
Also if you have to print anything then you should either use

```
<%
response.write  myDept 
%
```

>

and if you don't want to use response.write then you have to use asp<%=myDept%> tags in html.